# Duplication of concept requirement checks. Should we care about them?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

When functions nest, the concept requirement checks often duplicate.
Look at the example below,

```
template<typename I>
requires std::forward_iterator<I>
auto fun1(I i){ ... };

template<typename I>
requires std::forward_iterator<I>
auto fun2(I i){
    fun1(i);
    ....
}
```

fun1 is called inside fun2, thus `std::forward_iterator<I>` is checked twice.
I want to know whether this kind of duplication of requirement checks negatively affects compile time or not.
Or Do you think we should endeavor to reduce duplication of requirement checks?
Addition :
We can some what avoid the duplication of requirement checks like below,

```
template<typename I>
auto fun1_unchecked(I i) { ... }

template<typename I>
requires std::forward_iterator<I>
auto fun1(I i) {
    return fun1_unchecked(i);
}

template<typename I>
requires std::forward_iterator<I>
auto fun2(I i) {
    fun1_unchecked(i);
    ...
}
```

But I don't know this worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fun1` is called by someone other than `fun2`, then the presence of the concept is not duplication. Code which calls just `fun1` needs a conceptualized interface for it as well. They're two independent functions; one of them just so happens to call the other.

If `fun1` is *only called by `fun2`*, then the concept could be removed. But otherwise, it's a meaningful part of your system and should have a proper interface.

As for the compile-time costs of "duplication", the standard gives C++ implementations all the leeway they need to minimize any costs. For any given type `T`, if a compiler (of one file) sees `concept_name<T>`, the compiler can freely assume that every subsequent use of `concept_name<T>` will produce the same value. So it can effectively cache it.

So any costs of "duplication" should be minimized.

> Do you think we should endeavor to reduce duplication of requirement checks?

No. Not unless you have *actual* performance metrics from actual compilers which tell you that there is an actual performance problem.

Comment: Is it bad practice if constraint `fun2` requires that `fun1(i)` must be well-formed instead of constraint `I` must be `forward_iterator`?

Comment: @康桓瑋: I wouldn't do that. It's much clearer to the user to spell out what the constraints for the function are than to try to say "whatever that does". It would also not allow for subsumption or other tricks of actual concepts.

Comment: @NocolBolas, fun1 is supposed to be called independently. But I can also avoid duplication of requirement checks by separating the concept interface. It's difficult to explain in comment section, so I will edit original post. Wait a moment...

Comment: @a.tana Be aware that these are compile time checks anyway! So by adding the constraints you get clearer interfaces without runtime impact.

Comment: @a.tana: I updated my answer.